# Search with locale on Microsoft Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, isearch, keyboard-macros

I'm using Emacs on MS Windows and suddenly I noticed that when I press `C-s` (incremental search) the prompt shows `I-search [NL]:` which I presume is my locale. I still can search incrementally but I can't execute recorded macros anymore. The macro shows like:

```
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
SPC         ;; self-insert-command
<with-input-method>
```

And it fails, what's wrong? In the past I have seen some Windows settings with keyboards and so on, but I don't believe that's the case.

I'm on a company laptop where settings can be changed at (upper mgt)'s will.

Comment: found it. Nothing to do with Windows peculiarities. I accidently toggled the input method `C-\ `

Comment: Can you add your resolution as an answer, and accept it? That way the question won't remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. Nothing to do with Windows peculiarities. I accidentally toggled the input method with `C-\`